# De kio estas la etimologio de "saluton"?

Tags: etymology

*Saluton* estas mallonga por *mi donas al vi saluton*, kiel *bonan tagon*, ĉu ne? Angle, vi ne povas diri *I give you hello*, do kio *saluton* signifas sole? (Mi pardonpetas por la malbona gramatiko, mi ne estas fluenta)

*Saluton* is short for *mi donas al vi saluton* like *bonan tagon*, right? In English you can't say *I give you hello*, so what does *saluton* mean by itself?

Comment: You can still say _I bring you salutations_, which would be a better translation that _hello_.

Comment: `salut` in French is something like `hello` (more polite though); deriving from the verb _to greet_, _to salute_. I think `saluton` is definitely of French origin.

Answer (score 7):

There seems to be two questions here:

1. What does *saluton* mean alone?

According to [PIV](http://vortaro.net/#saluto), it means:

> Ekstera signo de ĝentileco, kiun oni esprimas per vortoj aŭ movoj al renkontata persono

Which roughly translated means:

> An external sign of politeness, that you express with words or movements to someone you recognise.

With this meaning, I don’t think there is anything weird about the phrase *mi donas al vi saluton*, except that if you actually said it it would probably sound very pompous. Just because in English we would say “hello” in the same situation as we would say “saluton” in Esperanto, doesn’t mean they have the same meaning. Perhaps a closer translation of the word in English could be a *greeting* or a *salutation*.

2. De kio estas “saluton” etimologio?

I would imagine the word has the same etymology as *salutation* in English. According to the [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/salutation), that comes from the Latin *salutatio*.